# Ionic run in device error

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem, When I try build my app using this command `cordova build android` it returns this error:

> Miftahs-MacBook-Air:foodinstory miftahali$ cordova build android
>   (node:12905) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (Parsing /Users/miftahali/projects/ionic/foodinstory/config.xml failed)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:171:17)
>       at EventEmitter.module.exports.emit (/Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/events.js:71:17)
>       at new ConfigParser (/Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigParser/ConfigParser.js:34:16)
>       at getScriptsFromConfigXml (/Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/scriptsFinder.js:107:21)
>       at getApplicationHookScripts (/Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/scriptsFinder.js:56:17)
>       at Object.getHookScripts (/Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/scriptsFinder.js:40:16)
>       at HooksRunner.fire (/Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:57:33)
>       at /Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/build.js:32:28
>       at _fulfilled (/Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at /Users/miftahali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30
>   (node:12905) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:12905) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

can help me resolve this, thanks

Comment: Which version of ionic are you using? And which of android-platform?

Comment: my ionic version 3.9.2, where i can see my android-platform version ?

Comment: `ionic cordova platform ls`

Comment: my android-platforms version android 6.3.0

Comment: thanks Matteo, i have problem in my config.xml because i not recheck after pull on git and its have conflict, thanks for all :)